# Component link is not resolving in DXA

Tags: dxa, link-resolver

If anybody has some context of component link resolving for richtextbox in DXA with .net

The RTF field has the following HTML inside `<a title="xyz" href="tcm:125-12345">linktext</a>`

I am trying to resolve it using  `@Html.DxaRichText(field)`

but it shows the plain text on the page. It does not show any link. I do not see any anchor tag in rendered HTML. Is there any method available in DXA to resolve the link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all is well, Component Links within rich text are stored in CM as XLinks. That is: as an `xlink:href` attribute (instead of just `href`, which is normally used in XHTML).

The DXA model mapping code automatically detects such XLinks and will resolve them to a Page URL (using CD Linking APIs), turning the XLink into a regular HTML hyperlink. See: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/master/Sdl.Web.Tridion/Mapping/DefaultRichTextProcessor.cs

Comment: The github link is broken.